# HTML Tables: fixed and dynamic widths

Tags: html, css

I have a table something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id='col1' style='width:120px;'>
            Content here...
        </td>
        <td id='col2' style='width:30px;'>
            Content here...
        </td>
        <td id='col3' style='width:35px;'>
            Content here...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want `col1` to be fixed at a width of `120px`. However `col2` and `col3` should have a dynamic width of the remaining table space. In relation to each other `30%` and `35%` respectively. (That is if `col2` is `300px` then `col3` should be `320px`.)

Comment: Are you using tables for layout purposes or for data representation?

Comment: Yeah, unless this is just a list to show bits of data in a simple way, don't use tables.

Comment: Yeah it's not the full table, just the relevant parts.

Comment: if the remanining take up all space. the col2 take 30%, col3 take 35%, what do you do with the last 35%?

Comment: No, it musn't be 30 and 35% of the table it must be 30 and 35% in relation to each other.

Comment: Or it can be 30 and 35% of the table (or any other number) and the remainder can just remain empty (perhaps in a fourth `td` as suggested below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `table-layout:fixed`? Not 100% on this but here is a quick mock that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/pm6pt/

Answer (score 4):

I assume that there is a fourth column somewhere to take up the remaining space? Regardless, you can adapt the following if not...

```
<table width="800"> <!-- or <table width="50%"> or <table style="width:800px"> etc -->
 <colgroup>
   <col width="120" />
   <col width="30%" />
   <col width="35%" />
   <col />
 </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
      <td>Col 3</td>
      <td>Col 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The first column is fixed at 120 pixels; the second and third columns are 30% and 35% respectively, with any remaning space being allocated to the fourth dynamically sized column.

Comment: this does not work. see here...http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/tCdEz/ try to enlarge the right frame, it doest take up the rest

Comment: @bingjie - Did you give the table an explicit width? If you don't provide a table width (i.e., style="width:100%"), then the table is sized to its contents, and the col widths are effectively ignored.

Comment: @Chaim - What determines your table size? Solely the content? Does the content change once loaded? Can you use jQuery to resize the table as required? Need more info about what exactly you are trying to accomplish. You can't ask the table to size a column by 30% if there isn't a fixed width to base that 30% off of.

Comment: @Calagary Ok I guess I could put a % width.

Comment: @Calgary, @bingjie2680: The jsfiddle example posted by bingjie2680 still doesn't seem to work even with adding a `style='width:100%'`

Comment: @Chaim - The table width can be either in px or %; as long as the table has a "width"; lnrbob's answer also relies on a table width as well.

Comment: @Calgary, @bingjie2680: Adding a `table-layout:fixed` as suggested below by lnrbob does make it work though.

Comment: @Chaim - I tested Bingie's jsfiddle, and it does work for me (IE9) with any of <table width="500">, <table width="80%">, <table style="width:80%"> or even using a style of table { width:80%; }; the layout fixed shouldn't be required...

Comment: Ok, that's funny. When I tried it didn't. (FF5) (Perhaps you can post a link of the jsfiddle with your corrections.) Also on my actual code it only worked with the layout fixed.

Comment: Also running lnrbob's example with the layout fixed (and changing the table width to a %) doesn't work.

Comment: @Chaim - Just checked Chrome and FF5 as well, worked as expected... I updated the code with a fixed with using the table width attribute as one example.

Comment: Oh I understand now. If you leave out fixed layout than when you make the area smaller (to hold to have the full width of the first col and the other cols, than it makes the first col smaller) if you do put fixed layout then the first col will be the same size no matter how small, or how big, the area is.